# wp_query random post

Tags: posts, wp-query, loop

I want to show all posts like `mywebsite.com/postname/1/`, `mywebsite.com/postname/2/` ...... `mywebsite.com/postname/7/` ..

Below code works perfectly for me, the only problem is that it shows only first posts `mywebsite.com/postname/`...

How can I do this?

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Random Post
 * This template will only display the content you entered in the page editor
 */
?>

<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<?php
/*
Random Post Picker
Use on page to send viewer to random post optionally mod query
*/

// set arguments for WP_Query on published posts to get 1 at random
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'order' => 'DESC',

    // Using the date_query to filter posts from last week
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after' => '2 week ago'
        )
    )
); 

// It's time! Go someplace random
$my_random_post = new WP_Query ( $args );

while ( $my_random_post->have_posts () ) {
  $my_random_post->the_post ();

  // redirect to the random post
  wp_redirect ( get_permalink () );
  exit;
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that ordering by `rand` is **extremely slow and expensive**, and that page can't be cached. Any vaguely competent hacker can now launch a cheap denial of service attack by pinging that URL repeatedly, to bring down your database server via resource exhaustion

Comment: i think the hacker will have better to do as doing attacks on my server.it is just a local website and not a top website.  about "slow"  there will not be more than 50-100 users online at same time.  still we can change from "rand" to something else.  first i have to get it to work as i want it.

Comment: I had only 4 or 5 concurrent users in mind when I wrote my comment, but it's a problem that can be sidestepped completely, my answer below will scale to billions of concurrent users while giving significantly faster page loads

Answer (score 6):

Doing this in PHP is an awful idea:

- This page is impossible to cache
- ordering by random is **extremely expensive** to query, involving creating temporary database tables, and scans, as it has to copy the entire posts table, then randomly re-order the posts, then finally do the actual query on the new table before destroying it
- This opens you up to resource exhaustion attacks

For example, this command will ping your random post URL repeatedly. Ran enough times on enough computers, it will bring down your database:

```
for i in `seq 1 20000`; do curl http://mywebsite.com/postname; done
```

If you're on a cheap shared host, it may be enough to call your URL in several browser tabs at the same time to trigger problems.

Not to mention that your redirect sends out HTTP headers, but the code outputs tags beforehand, so headers have already been sent, breaking things and triggering PHP warnings.

### The Super Fast Easy Alternative

So instead, do a normal query ordered by data, and output the data as JSON. Then in javascript on the browser, randomly pick one of those posts and do a client side redirect.

This way the page can be cached, your database is protected, and the browser does all the heavy lifting. The database query will be **very** fast in comparison

Now your problem is as simple as outputting a bit of data in a list, randomly picking something from the list in JS, then using `window.location= ...` to redirect. No WP knowledge necessary

Comment: +1 for the client-side alternative. But one question here, setting random in `WP_Query` will pick a random post amongst let's say, 15,000 posts. But is it efficient to send a JSON response containing at least 15K strings to the browser?

Comment: No, sending 15k posts isn't efficient, nor is querying for 15k posts. Anything involving random and databases is going to be excessively expensive. Instead provide a smarter choice, e.g. the 20 most recent posts, or the 20 most commented on posts. There are so many alternatives to random when listing posts, and random rarely means what people think of it as anyway. If the site returned the same post 10 times, that would be a valid output of a truly random selection, as would 5 posts all in a row, but people really mean 10 posts evenly distributed across the range

Comment: So, what do you suggest for a blog that has thousands of posts? Is setting a random offset and then querying 1 post a good idea?

Comment: no, my suggestion is to not try to randomly pick from thousands of posts, in the same way that withdrawing £1m from the bank is just as costly no matter if you do it via card, cheque, or other means. Random is a bad idea, truly random is even worse, you have to compromise and give the appearance of randomness, or limit your scope. There are a huge number of alternatives that look the same, getting a truly random number from 15k posts without knowing them all in advance is fundamentally expensive

Comment: Interesting. But if the user is viewing a cached version of the page (page caching), it wouldn't matter, right? Obviously, the randomised returned post will stay the same until the cache has been flushed. Unless of course somehow the `'orderby' => 'rand'` triggers fragmented caching...

Comment: Yeah you'd have to cache just those parts of the page, unless you did it in javascript, eitherway random is an awful idea, and never means what you intend anyway

Comment: hi Tom, I know this post is old, but can you provide an example of this in with json? i don't even know where to start.

Comment: @rudtek any REST API endpoint will return JSON formatted data, and JSON is the same as objects and arrays in javascript, e.g. `[1,2,3,4,5]` is JSON, it's also an array in javascript. How you would randomly pick an item in an array in JS is a Q for stackoverflow, and how you would decode a JSON response from an AJAX call is also a stackoverflow Q, as is how to include an array of items in a HTML page for use in JS. For everything else, there's `json_encode`, standard vanilla PHP. Honestly there's very little WordPress involved if any

Comment: There is also the middle way in PHP: `shuffle($my_random_post->posts)` - if used directly before the loop - will also make "random" order - **but note, that sorting large number of posts *RANDOMLY* will be always very expensive and can be better handled in browser as @TomJNowell suggests!**

Comment: Shuffling it in PHP works too, the cost is in making the database do the randomness, if you can move that elsewhere, be it PHP or the browser, or pre-calculated, then you gain major improvements

Answer (score 5):

Only 1 post is displaying on your side because of you are using `exit()` in your loop. In your code when WP_Query start and loop exit after one counter.
Remove `exit()` and use this code:

```
<?php
/*
 * Random Post Picker
 * Use on page to send viewer to random post optionally mod query
 */

// set arguments for WP_Query on published posts to get 1 at random
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'order' => 'DESC',

    // Using the date_query to filter posts from last week
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after' => '2 week ago'
        )
    )
);

// It's time! Go someplace random
$my_random_post = new WP_Query ( $args );
if($my_random_post->have_posts()){
    while ( $my_random_post->have_posts () ) {
        $my_random_post->the_post ();
        echo '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: i want only one post to be displayed and i want the redirect to full post.
the template uses "mywebsite.com/random/,,,,  when the visitor uses mywebsite.com/random/  i want the user to be redirected to the full post, but randomly to all posts, like i have explained " mywebsite.com/postname/15/..... and soo on, the post is like a gallery, with "next post"  i want that the visitor is redirected randomly to some post number, not just the post.

Comment: You want to redirect user at another page.

Comment: using my random page i redirect users to random post. same domain. 
mypage.com/random/ to mypage.com/somepost/ .... mypage.com/anotherpost/....  untill this point is all ok, i want more.... > mypage.com/somepost/2/..mypage.com/somepost/3

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. Tell me first this code permalink in not working or you want to change the permalink of the posts.Please clarify your task.

Comment: @adikica if you are PHP redirecting => you must do that BEFORE any HTML is put out ... not in the middle of the template - you can use client-side javascript redirect, or use `template_redirect` action

Comment: @adikica Also if you are calling exit() after first post, there is no loop - so just use `if` statement

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to redirect the user to the random post page, and you can't even if you want, because you can't be redirected to multiple places at the same time.

So, simply output your random posts inside your loop:

```
while ( $my_random_post->have_posts () ) {
  $my_random_post->the_post ();
  echo '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
}
```